# How to completely remove audio channels from video

Tags: audio, video, mp4, gif

Telegram displays soundless MP4s as GIFs.
 How can I completely remove audio from my MP4 files? I tried `Filmora` but it only detaches audio. While exporting it still includes silenced audio channels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) its really simple:

```
ffmpeg -i videoAndAudio.mp4 -c copy -an onlyVideo.mp4
```

`-i path/to/input_file`: give the path to your file

`-c copy`: tell FFmpeg to copy codecs (prevent transcoding)

`-an`: disables audio

Answer (score 1):

As ffmpeg alternative, use Virtual dub:

- open the target file
- set video to 'direct stream copy'
- set audio to none
- save as new file

The process should be almost as fast as a direct file copy.

Answer (score 0):

If it's easier for you to use GUI, there is an open source app called VCT https://sourceforge.net/projects/videoconvertertranscoder/?source=directory

It's a GUI for ffmpeg. Download and install it. It contains ffmpeg so you're good to go.

1. Select your input file, in Video Container select checkbox *Copy* and in *Extract Video or Audio* select box *Video only*.
2. Click *Add to batch list* and then click *Start*. Your file will be encoded within an minute, without audio stream, only video.
3. In the textbox you can see ffmpeg command, you can change name or destination folder.

[image]